# When to dispose of mouse events using Rx in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

Given the following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mouseMove = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
            eventHandler => this.MouseMove += eventHandler,
            eventHandler => this.MouseMove -= eventHandler);

        var mouseMoveSubscription = mouseMove.Subscribe(args =>
        {
            //Do Something
        });
    }
}
```

Where is the correct\best place to dispose\unsubscribe from mouseMoveSubscription given I want the subscription to follow the MainWindow's lifetime.  My main concern is I don't cause a memory leak that lasts past the windows lifetime.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best place from the window lifetime point of view is the **[`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx)** event.

It is the beginning of the window's shutdown process (as shown **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Window_Lifetime_Events)** or **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403418/Lifetime-events-of-a-WPF-application)**) - I find it better to unload everything as soon as I know it is to be unloaded (or unsubscribed in this case). If you need to keep subscribed as long as possible for any reason, use the `Closed` even instead.

Comment: If I do it in the closing event but I have several subscribers to closing event and one of them tries to cancel the close how would you handle that situation.

Comment: I'd use the `Closed` event then. It only gets fired when the window is really closed. There's one more event after that, `Unloaded`, but AFAIK there are some problems with it.

Answer (score 3):

To do this in a more composable way with Rx, consider creating an Observable stream from the 'CloseEvent' the people above have already mentioned.

e.g.
var closingObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern(this.Closing... etc)
Then, amend your query to use TakeUntil:
mouseMove.TakeUntil(closingObservable).Subscribe(args =>

You then needn't concern yourselve with explicit disposal.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with @Honza that `Closing` is the appropriate place to do this - but I follow this pattern generally for "hosted" `IDisposables`; it might be a touch overkill in places, but I find it to be a lightweight-enough pattern that it is generally applicable:

```
// Window, application, etc - some longish-living object
public class Something : IDisposable
{
    CompositeDisposable _disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    public Something()
    {
         // A composite disposable acts like a "bucket" of IDisposables
         // that are all disposed when the bucket is disposed.
          _disposables.Add(SomeObservable.Subscribe(...));
          _disposables.Add(SomeOtherObservable.Subscribe(...));
          _disposables.Add(YetAnotherObservable.Subscribe(...));

         // Here, optionally wire some "Yo, I should dispose when this happens" handler
         this.Closed += (o,e) => Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // clean up managed resources here
            if(_disposables != null)
            {
                _disposables.Dispose();
            }
        }   
        // clean up unmanaged resources here
    }

    ~Something()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```